# How can I import settings from Outlook 2007 to Thunderbird?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, thunderbird, migration, import

I'm looking for a solution to import my Outlook 2007 mailbox settings into Mozilla Thunderbird.

I have a few accounts installed in Outlook 2007, and I'd like to export all the settings to my Mozilla Thunderbird, without having to do it one by one.

Are there any tools or a solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go the the "Tools" menu, select "Import...", and then individually import your mail, address books, or settings from Outlook

EDIT: look here http://lifehacker.com/340521/import-outlook-pst-files-into-thunderbird-with-pst-import

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when you try? Error message? Can't find a PST? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TB build into the import tool, the trick is to use the 32bit version if you wanna transfer from older oUtlook versions...

Comment: The existing answer already seems to reference this and has more information. Avoid answering old questions unless you have significant new and different information to add.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180740)